# Restart Media Player Sound if Running

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I'm writing code for a two player same device game.

Whenever one player presses a particular button, I want a sound to play. The sound I found lasts less than 1 second. Another player can press a similar button, and it causes the same sound to play.

Unfortunately, if the sound is already playing, the button doesn't make the sound I want it to. I tried stop and prepare, but it doesn't seem to be working - could it be because I'm doing it too quickly? Is there a better way to do this?

```
 if (mpSwap.isPlaying())
{
//Stop it, and restart it
mpSwap.stop();
try
{
mpSwap.prepare();
} 
catch (IllegalStateException e)
{
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
catch (IOException e)
{
//TODO Auto-Generated catch block
}               

mpSwap.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html), not a media player.

A media player can play only one sound at a time.  You'd need 2 MediaPlayers to play 2 different sounds.  Also MediaPlayer will have higher latency at beginning of playback as it loads from disk, while a SoundPool stores resources in RAM.

So, use SoundPool. It was designed for precisely your problem.